# SAP Business One for HANA Web Access: HTTP Status 500 - Initialization of SLD service is failed

Tags: hana, http-status-code-500, sapb1

We updated SAP Business One for HANA from 9.2 PL04 to PL06.

In PL04 Browser Access works fine, but in PL06 we get the following message:

[image: Initialization of SLD service is failed]

Additionally the system was re-configured to use hostname instead of IP and use a SSL certificates.

I hope someone know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem with 9.2 PL06, and could resolve it reinstalling de Browser Access.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SLD host address configuration file: 
...tomcat\conf\SLD-config.xml

There you should have a valid accessible host-name under XML element:

    https://YOURHOST:443

Also make sure you have the URL that you are accessing the service in SLD external address mapping.

Alternatively you could also try the solution in SAP note: [[2442627]](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2442627)